# primefaces: uneditable columns in editable datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have an editable dataTable, I want to add checkbox to the header which controls the editable mode of the column.
which mean, every column has a checkbox in it's header, if the checkbox is selected the columns will be uneditable, which means we can not edit any data in the cells.

how can I do that ??

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable of type **boolean** for each column

```
 <p:selectBooleanCheckbox  value="#{Yourbean.EditableColumn1}" />
 <p:selectBooleanCheckbox  value="#{Yourbean.EditableColumn2}" />
 <p:selectBooleanCheckbox  value="#{Yourbean.EditableColumn3}" />
```

Let's say you want to have inputText boxes in your column values, you may control if it's editable by the disabled attribute.

```
 <p:dataTable>
   <p:column id="column1">
      <h:inputText disabled="#{YourBean.EditableColumn1}">
   </p:column>
   <p:column id="column2">
      <h:inputText disabled="#{YourBean.EditableColumn2}">
   </p:column>
   <p:column id="column3">
      <h:inputText disabled="#{YourBean.EditableColumn3}">
   </p:column>
 </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Did you test your solution?

Comment: I tested @Pellizon, but I am aware it is missing model updates. I just didn't post, because I don't know the way he wanna have them updated.